# Floating point issue with -[NSNumberFormatter numberFromString:]

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm now dealing with the conversion from NSString to NSNumber with NSNumberFormatter. But when I try to convert a string which contains a floating point, sometimes it will return some strange value. For example,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:@"95.665"];
NSLog(@"%@", num);
```

The log will display 95.66500000000001. Can anyone give me some advices to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It's a binary floating-point number. 95.665 is not a number that can be represented exactly as a floating-point number, so you got a number that was a tiny bit larger. It's normal, and nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks gnasher729. Now I convert the string by using NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: did you try  
num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:@"95.665".doubleValue];